# Makefile error (make: *** [Makefile:31: test] Error -1073741515)

Tags: python, django, makefile

I am trying to set up my local development environment using the make command `make setup` as and I get this error.

## Error code:

```bash
make: *** [Makefile:31: test] Error -1073741515
```

## Make File:

This is part of the Makefile content, **/Makefile**

```
local_config = --settings=config.local
...
setup:  # Set up the project database
    python manage.py migrate ${local_config}
```

## Config.local:

This is the content of the **/config/local.py**

```py
from .settings import *

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "db.sqlite3"),
    }
}

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache",
    }
}

DEBUG = True
TASTYPIE_FULL_DEBUG = True
```

I expected the command to execute normally and setup my development environment.

Comment: This error message means that `make` invoked the command at line 31 of `Makefile`, and that command exited with an exit code of `-1073741515`.  Make considers an exit code of anything other than `0` to be a failure and reports it as such.  Hopefully there are some other error messages that were printed before the one you have shown us, that will help you discover what the problem is.

Comment: Yes the command being invoked is `python manage.py migrate --settings=config.local` . However, nothing happens.
I even thought is was due to the python version and I tried using different versions, but nothing...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "nothing happens".  Are you saying that there are no message printed between the invocation of the command and the error message make prints?  Please edit your question and cut and paste the complete output you see, starting with the command line make prints up to the error message make prints.